# How to download file from SQL Server database chunk by chunk in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, stream, entity-framework-core

We've written file sharing web application, and we've stored data in SQL Server database. We need to download files from database chunk by chunk. For instance, each chunk is 1MB.
If data become 10MB, we must download it base on ten chunks and finally, we must merge them into one file.

I've found an article But, unfortunately, it's not about downloading files from the database. 
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/march/download-file-in-chunks-in-parallel-in-c/

Comment: Do you know what this code is doing?  It is opening the same file up X number of times and then moving to a different chunk and downloading.  Do you know the overhead this method takes?  I would recommend putting results into a view and then do the split by number of rows of in the view.

Comment: You can still use the [substring() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) on `varbinary(max)` columns (which I'm assuming you're using to store your file data), but it's not terribly efficient - it still has to read the whole file out of LOB storage before operating on it with `substring()`. If it's a fixed 1MB chunk size for all files in your system maybe you need a "parts" table that stores a 1MB chunk per row.

Comment: Just don't. Large files really don't belong in databases. They have their own kind of database called a filesystem. It seems like you're already butting up against some of the unnatural issues that emerge from storing files in a database. For your own good health, reconsider this decision.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean of view? I didn't get it.

Comment: A view in SQL Server is a temporary database table where the output of query is stored.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017